# Maintain the status of global variables of dynamic library in CGO

Tags: c, go, global-variables, cgo, stateful

I use a C library in Go code by using CGO. The problem is that it seems that the state of the global variables is not maintained each time the C functions are called.

This library has a global variable and a series of initialization functions. Calling initialization functions has no effect. It is as if the entire memory allocated to the library is cleared after each function is executed. And each function is executed independently.

Does anyone have experience in this area what should I set?

PS: I’m not created a reference to those global variables in Go. This global variable is a struct that has not been exported. Its definition is not in the main .h of the library.  Is there a way to preserve this global variable without changing the C-library code? (Thanks to: TehSphinX)

The variable is: **swed** in https://www.astro.com/ftp/swisseph/src/sweph.h

```
extern TLS struct swe_data swed;
```

Comment: That's not at all normal, but without a [mcve] it is difficult to say more.

Comment: Are you keeping a reference to those global variables in Go? The Go GC will clean up any memory that Go is not keeping a reference to. This might help: https://go101.org/article/unsafe.html. To say more, we need to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

The `TLS` you have in your declaration suggests that the C library is using [Thread Local Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage).  This means there is more than one instance of the global variable.  What you're seeing is how accessing the different instances, from different C-language-level threads, results in accessing different variables.

There is no defined binding between Go's goroutines and C-language-level threads.  Go executors ("M"s, in the internal runtime, which changes from one Go release to another) do actually sit atop POSIX-style threads on many systems, but a goroutine may hop from one thread to another rather unpredictably.  To make TLS work at all, you *are* guaranteed that a call into C code lands in some thread and stays there until the C code returns to the Go code.  What you're not guaranteed, and have no control over, is *which* C thread runs at this point.

You'll have to pick some way to stick to one particular C thread, or defeat the TLS setup, to make any progress here.